# Add dynamically generated CSS to <head> for a specific page

Tags: magento-1.9

I have custom css

```
 <style>
        .flip-clock-wrapper ul li a div div.inn {
            background-color: **<?php echo '#' . $timerColor;?> !important;**
        }
    </style>
```

in view.phtml; But i want to add this css to `<head>` only for this page.
So how to add this css to page `<head>` ?

Comment: It depends on where the variable `$timerColor` gets it's data from. That variable might not be available in the head

Comment: i had updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you talk about the catalog product `view.phtml` ?

1. Create a `local.xml` in your theme
2. Add the following code:

   ```
   <catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="head">
       <block type="core/template" name="mycss" template="page/mycss.phtml">
   </reference>
   </catalog_product_view>
   ```
3. Put your code in `page/mycss.phtml`